# Ajax в Laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, pagination

имеется такой контроллер:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HotelsController extends Controller {

protected $request;

public function __construct(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index($page = null)
{
    if($this->request->ajax()) {
        return "Hello!";
    } else {

        $data = $this->request->all();

        $children = $data['children'];
        $destination = $data['destination'];
        $rooms = $data['rooms'];
        $adults = $data['adults'];
        $currency = $data['currency'];
        $checkIn = $data['checkin'];
        $checkOut = $data['checkout'];

        if ($children != 0)
            $searchString = 'Hotels in ' . $destination . '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $rooms .' room(s), ' . $adults . ' adult(s), ' . $children . ' children(s)&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        else
            $searchString = 'Hotels in ' . $destination . '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $rooms .' room(s), ' . $adults . ' adult(s)&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;';

        $url = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?apikey=xm9gfyzzuz58fqymn9fgzue4&cid=55505&destinationString='.str_replace(' ', '', $destination).'&currencyCode='.$currency.'&sort=TRIP_ADVISOR&customerSessionId=&arrivalDate=07/08/2015&departureDate=07/10/2015&numberOfResults=27&room1=2&_type=json';

        $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
        $hotelsInfo = $response->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary;
        $begin = $page * 27;
        $end = $begin + 27;
        $hotels = array_slice($hotelsInfo, $begin, $end);
        $count = $response->HotelListResponse->HotelList->{'@activePropertyCount'};
        $lastPage = ceil($count / 27);

        return view('hotels.index', [
            'hotels' => $hotels,
            'searchString' => $searchString,
            'count' => $count,
            'currentPage' => ($page == null) ? 1 : $page,
            'lastPage' => $lastPage,
            'destination' => $destination,
            'checkIn' => $checkIn,
            'checkOut' => $checkOut,
            'rooms' => $rooms,
            'adults' => $adults,
            'children' => $children,
            'currency' => $currency,
        ]);
    }

}
```

}

есть шаблон пагинации:

```
<nav class="pull-right">
@if ($count > 1)
    <ul class="pagination">
        @if ($currentPage != 1 && $lastPage >= 5)
            <li>
                <a href="hotels/" > << </a>
            </li>
        @endif
        @if($currentPage != 1)
            <li>
                <a href="hotels/{{ $currentPage - 1 }}" > < </a>
            </li>
        @endif
        @for($i = $currentPage; $i <= $lastPage && $i <= $currentPage + 4; $i++)
            <li class="{{($currentPage == $i) ? ' active' : '' }}">
                <a href="hotels/{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</a>
            </li>
        @endfor
        @if ($currentPage != $lastPage)
            <li>
                <a href="hotels/{{ $currentPage + 1 }}" > > </a>
            </li>
        @endif
        @if ($currentPage != $lastPage && $lastPage >= 5)
            <li>
                <a href="hotels/{{ $lastPage }}" > >> </a>
            </li>
        @endif
    </ul>
@endif
```

по нажатию на страничку должен отправляться ajax запрос, но он не отправляется а срабатывает обычный переход по ссылке, путь в самой ссылке указан для лучшей индексации, как делать так чтобы по клику срабатывал именно ajax запрос?
Вот сам код скрипта:

```
$(".pagination li a").on('click', function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
    var destination = $("#destination").val();
    var checkin = $("#checkin").val();
    var checkout = $("#checkout").val();
    var rooms = $("#rooms").val();
    var adults = $("#adults").val();
    var children = $("#children").val();
    var currency = $("#currency").val();
    var _token = $("#_token").val();
    var data = {
        _token: _token,
        destination: destination,
        checkin: checkin,
        checkout: checkout,
        rooms: rooms,
        adults: adults,
        children: children,
        currency: currency
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#hotelsInfo").html(data);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отменить действие ссылки.

Попробуйте в самом конце вернуть false:

```
 $(".pagination li a").on('click', function(e){
        // Ваш код
        return false;
 });
```

Иногда **e.preventDefault()** недостаточно.